# Problem with Deinstalling AVG Antivirus

Tags: uninstall, avg-antivirus

I have a problem with deinstaling my AVG Antivirus on Windows. I tried to uninstall it with Revo Uninstaller but no luck. Here are some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the AVG remover tools provided [here](http://www.avg.com/us-en/utilities)?

Actually almost all antivirus vendors provide some kind of uninstall/cleanup/remover tool. Maybe they are aware that their uninstallers are crap and do often fail to remove all traces of their own product ;).

Comment: Glad they have a 2011 uninstaller now! That one is a beast to remove.